# CPU usage logger for process (Windows)

Tags: windows, monitoring, logs, system-monitor

I am looking for a (preferably free) logger application for Windows which logs the CPU usage of the process & also total CPU.

Functionality I am looking for:

• Logs total CPU every second

• Check if total CPU is going more than 80% & logs the CPU usage of highest CPU taking process

• Logs the processes (i.e. 2-3 with high CPU)

Comment: For something specific like that, if you know how to code, I'd suggest you to write your own, for example using PowerShell. Some initial ideas on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[powershell]+cpu+is%3Aquestion) (`[powershell] cpu is:question`)

Comment: I assume [a solution like ProcessMonitor](https://superuser.com/questions/453909/log-cpu-by-process-over-time) is too verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend our tool [SysKit, formerly Terminal Services Log](https://www.syskit.com), and it does exactly what you need. The thresholds (e.g. 80% CPU) can easily be adjusted, and you can receive alerts when it goes over your desired threshold. Unfortunately, the tool is not free, but give it a spin, download free trial, and if you still think it should be free, contact us.

Please note: I work for [Acceleratio](https://acceleratio.net), the makers of the tool mentioned above, so I might be a little bit biased here.